# Why is Escher's waterfall considered a perpetual motion machine of the first kind?

Tags: thermodynamics, perpetual-motion

I know that perpetual motion machines can't work because of friction, but intuitively I thought that Escher's waterfall (https://cdn.churchm.ag/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/waterfall-illusion-e1302170121549.jpg) couldn't work because of the absence of external energy. I can't see where friction prevents this process from working. Any ideas? Thanks in advance and have a good day :)

Answer (score 6):

Escher's waterfall doesn't work because you can't fall off a cliff, then go downhill and end up where you started. It's geometry, not physics.

Comment: Better repeat the subject, in your last sentence. At first I took it reverse way, wanted to correct you by saying Escher waterfall is art and geometry not physics :) than realise what you meant.

Comment: Okay but I need an answer based on physics.

Comment: @musicinmyheart well you could argue that geometry (since GR) is physics....

Comment: You can recouch it in physics terms: gravity is a conservative force and so it can't decrease all the way around a loop.